# creating Cell with SwiftUI view causing overlap in List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I do have Swift UI view here

```
struct ETableViewCell: View {
let appointment: Appointment

var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 10) {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(appointment.patientName ?? "unknown")
                .font(.body)
            Text(appointment.gender?.rawValue ?? "unknown")
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
        .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
  }
}
```

And calling tableview cell like this

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueCell(for: indexPath) as CustomHostingCell
 cell.configure(for: appointment)
 return cell
```

and custom cell is here

```
final class CustomHostingCell: UITableViewCell {

override init(style _: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    backgroundColor = .white
    selectionStyle = .default
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func configure(for appointment: Appointment) {
    let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: EncounterTableViewCell(appointment: appointment))
    contentView.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    vc.view.edgeAnchors == contentView.edgeAnchors
    vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
}
}
```

SO I am loading view to enter information and hitting save .. after that list view will update but somehow I am getting weird UI.enter image description here

Any help would be appreciated and Thanks in advance. enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Do you really need to mix SwiftUI and UIKit?

Comment: thats a wild mix of SwiftUI and UIKit. You should stick with one of them.